# C# project, problem how use files in project directory Resources

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2019, project, embedded-resource

i did research about this, but nothing worked.

I created folder in my project in Visual Studio 2019 => `Images` and i placed a file `footer.png` here.

In Visual Studio => Right click on folder `Images`, added new item `Resources` and add this line => `Name` -> `FooterBG` and `Value` -> `Images/footer.png`

in code:

```
string pathToFooter = Resource.FooterBG;
```

in debug get return Images\footer.png

When i want to add this to string with html tags, dont work:

```
String htmlTags = "<table background='"+ pathToFooter + "'><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

Please any tips what im doing wrong ?

Comment: how about the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, the pathToFooter is not the actual path of the image.

Here is a code example you can refer to:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pathToFooter = Resource1.FooterBG;
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + Path.Combine(@"../..", pathToFooter);
            String htmlTags = "<table background='" + path + "' width='1000'  height='800' align='center'><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>";
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlTags;
        }
```

Result:

[image]